# localhost/phpmyadmin showing error access denied

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I installed xampp on my machine. everything is okay but the phpmyadmin doesn't open up. It is listed with numerous errors as shown in figure or as

```
 MySQL said:
Cannot connect: invalid settings.

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I tried editing the username and password and also host address in `config.inc.php` but it is not helping anyway.

Can anyone show me a light here??

[image: phpmyadmin access denied error]

Comment: can you login manually with the phpmyadmin account ? please give a little bit more information.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably misconfigured PHPMyAdmin.

You can reconfigure it by using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`.

Comment: I did that but the same problem remains.